# c++ compilation error: call of overloaded ‘<function_name>(char*&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, ambiguous

I'm trying to convert a code in C to C++ language and I get an error but I've no idea
what's the source of the problem.

here is the source code: http://pastebin.com/PnKvgNsR

The error message is:

```
call of overloaded ‘dateTimeToMinutes(char*&)’ is ambiguous
```

Compiling with g++4.7.1 (included c++11 standard).

Comment: Post the pertinent sections here, don't have the time to go elsewhere...

Comment: You must have another decl of dateTimeToMinutes in your header file.

Comment: We dont have idea what's source of the problem too, post some code

Comment: There may be another declaration of `dateTimeToMinutes()` that is not in the `RabQavSystem` namespace. Since you are `using namespace RabQavSystem;`, that may cause the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cpp file specify the namespace RabQavSystem in your definitions of dateTimeXXX functions.

```
int RabQavSystem::dateTimeDifference(DateTime datetime1, DateTime datetime2) 
{
    ...
}

int RabQavSystem::dateTimeToMinutes(DateTime datetime)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man !
I thought I tried to be more specific but it really worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

In your header, you declare two functions in the `RabQavSystem` namespace:

```
namespace RabQavSystem {
    int dateTimeToMinutes(DateTime datetime);
    int dateTimeDifference(DateTime datetime1, DateTime datetime2);
}
```

In your source file, you declare and define new functions in the global namespace; these are not definitions of the functions declared in the header, but of different functions in a different namespace:

```
int dateTimeDifference(DateTime datetime1, DateTime datetime2) {
    // ....
}

int dateTimeToMinutes(DateTime datetime) {
    // ....
}
```

Then `using namespace RabQavSystem;` pulls the other function names into the global namespace, causing the ambiguity.

To fix it, you want to define the functions in your namespace, not the global namespace:

```
int RabQavSystem::dateTimeDifference(DateTime datetime1, DateTime datetime2) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

int RabQavSystem::dateTimeToMinutes(DateTime datetime) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```